# how to use fetch with await?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have an express server that is responding with jwt.
in my front-end I'm using fetch to make request,

my code:

```
try {
      const option = {
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'cors',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
      }

      fetch("http://localhost:5000/auth/login",option)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.json());
    })
```

and in my console i can see:

```
Promise { <state>: "pending" }
 <state>: "fulfilled"
 <value>: Object { bearer: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE2NjYwNzk0MzcsImV4cCI6MTY2NjA4MzAzNywiYXVkIjoiNjAxZDMxMTYtNDc2Ny00NjFiLTgwYjctMzY3OTM3ZGEzNmFjIiwiaXNzIjoicGFwYV9qaSJ9.62-IC_Q8CjPAE1T09pJXYTSlZGa-0tVsryRAhnF7Plk" } ​
 <prototype>: Promise.prototype { … }
```

my problem is that I want to use it with awit, but my await code is not giving me the jwt.

my await code:

```
try {
      const option = {
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'cors',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
      }

      let datactl = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/auth/login",option)
      console.log(datactl)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
```

in console, i can see

```
Response { type: "cors", url: "http://localhost:5000/auth/login", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "OK", headers: Headers(2), body: ReadableStream, bodyUsed: false }
body: ReadableStream { locked: false }
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers { "content-length" → "222", "content-type" → "application/json; charset=utf-8" }
ok: true
redirected: false ​
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: "cors"
url: "http://localhost:5000/auth/login"
<prototype>: ResponsePrototype { clone: clone(), arrayBuffer: arrayBuffer(), blob: blob(), … }
login.js:41
```

it is showing status 200, but there is no jwt in the response. can you please tell me how to convert .then code into await code so that i can get the jwt

Comment: did you forget `const data = await datactl .json()` ? you can't see that the second code doesn't *read* the JSON whereas the first does?

Comment: Fetch returns a [Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) which also needs to be awaited (with the right method), most likely `const result = await response.json();`